# var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "Theme.MyThemeActionbar",}); not working in local file but working fine in tiapp.xml

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I have set up the styles in platform/android/res/values/mycustomtheme.xml where I am trying to access the style property set in the XML from js file using the below line but it is not working.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "MyThemeActionbar"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you call you theme inside that XML file.
E.g. my theme XML starts like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MyThemeActionbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
```

and I use the following TSS:

```
"Window" : {
    theme: "Theme.MyThemeActionbar"
}
```

Comment: is the XML content is in the views folder or whether it is in the /platform folder?

Comment: as mentioned in the other thread the theme xml has to be in `app/platform/android/res/values/mytheme.xml`. The `/platform` (in the root) folder is a generated folder. The `views` folder is for Alloy XMLs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359386/i-am-unable-to-apply-theme-appcompat-notitlebar-and-colorprimarydark-status/54359973#54359973