# i am unable to apply "Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar" and "colorPrimaryDark" status bar color property at the same time

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I want to hide the action bar throughout the application and also want to set the status bar color? in Appcelerator titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the official guide at https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Action+Bar

You can either hide it in code `win.activity.actionBar.hide();` in the open event and use a normal style in the theme xml or you set your parent in the theme to
`<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar">`.

Statusbar color is a theme item:
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff0000</item>`. You can add into your theme.

Here is a style I'm using as an example:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#00d59e</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff225c</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#999999</item>
</style>
```

using

```
"Window" : {
    theme: "Theme.MyTheme",
    barColor: "#ff225c"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept my custom theme file inside

```
App->Platform->Android->res->values->mytheme.xml
```

and my xml file looks like below and it works fine for me..

```
 <resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in tiapp.xml file inside maifest

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.May be it will help you. -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name));
        }
```

Comment: the question is about Titanium not native Android

Comment: @miga,


I tried the following source code of yours. I wasn't working with iOS. May I know why it wasn't working?

https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.barcode

Comment: @faizal very unrelated to the question and the reply. But yes: `A barcode scanner example for Android using Hyperloop`. It is only using an Android library, so it won't run on iOS and is not designed to do so

Comment: Thanks @miga so what if it has to be implemented in IOS as well

Comment: then feel free to do that :) I didn't want to because I don't use Hyperloop on iOS. But there are multiple barcode modules for iOS already so just use them. But please: use google, ti-slack. This is not the topic of this SO post!